# Error message when defining struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am writing a struct in Swift:

```
struct LevelDictionary {
    let kNumberOfSegments: Int = 10

    static func loadLevelData() -> NSDictionary {
        for var segmentNumber = 0; segmentNumber < kNumberOfSegments; ++segmentNumber {
       //My code here
        }
    return dictionary
    }
}
```

For some reason I get an error on compiling: `Instance member 'kNumberOfSegments' cannot be used on type 'LevelDictionary'`. What am I missing? I get the same error when I set up LevelDictionary as a Class.

Comment: you can't initialise kNumberOfSegments into structure body....complier does permit it....pl. remove the initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that you can't use a property in class scope.

A different answer is that you seem to want a static function that returns a dictionary after doing something a certain number of times; which is why you have `kNumberOfSegments` in the first place. But do you really need to have a variable for something that you aren't going to use again. Another way to do this is to have a default variable in your class method:

```
struct LevelDictionary {

    static func loadLevelData(numberOfSegments: Int = 10) -> NSDictionary {
        for segment in 0 ..< numberOfSegments {
            // your code here
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

Now you can call the method without an argument to use the default

```
let dictionary = LevelDictionary.loadLevelData() // Will use 10 segments
```

Or you can use a parameter to override the default

```
let dictianary = LevelDictionary.loadLevelData(20) // Will use 20 segments
```

Answer (score 4):

`loadLevelData()` is a static function which is called on "class" level

```
LevelDictionary.loadLevelData()
```

To use `kNumberOfSegments` in the static function it must be static as well

```
static let kNumberOfSegments: Int = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use instance member variables/constants inside the static function. (In terms of Objective C you can't use instance member objects inside class function)

Either you should declare the `kNumberOfSegments` as `static` or make that function as non-static. I prefer the first option,

```
struct LevelDictionary
{
    static let kNumberOfSegments: Int = 10

    static func loadLevelData() -> NSDictionary
    {
        for var segmentNumber = 0; segmentNumber < kNumberOfSegments; ++segmentNumber
        {
            //My code here
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```